# multi value cell separated by comma to array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm stuck at a point where I have to split and copy multi-value cell of entire column(C) which are separated by comma to an array. and arrange it to the corresponding column
**Suppose:**

```
  C1 = oranges,grapes,apple ; C2 = apple,mango ; C786 = watermelon,oranges,plum
```

It should go to it respective column, all the values of mango should go to column E and apple to F, watermelon to G and rest to next column
What I want To achieve is

```
Initially -::-

    A           B                 E     F           G       H      I      J     K
  Seller   FruitSell            Mango  Apple  Watermelon Grapes Orange  Plum Banana
 Seller1  Oranges,Grapes,Apple            
 Seller2  Only Mango            
 Seller3  Plum,Banana
```

---

```
 Output :-:          
    A           B                 E     F           G       H      I      J     K
  Seller   FruitSell            Mango  Apple  Watermelon Grapes Orange  Plum Banana
 Seller1  Oranges,Grapes,Apple         Apple             Grapes Orange    
 Seller2  Only Mango            Mango
 Seller3  Plum,Banana                                                   Plum Banana
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post your current code and a more detailed description of your data (not clear to me what values are where)

Comment: So you have a designated column for each fruit? You can solve this even without VBA.

Comment: @user3598756 I have given more detailed description

Comment: @MladenSavic I want to solve this with VBA, but any help is welcome

Comment: You could handle the designated columns, by having a dictionary/collection for the specifics, then looping the array from `split` and checking each one.  Wouldn't a formula in each be better, something like `=IF(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH(", apples",A1))),"apples","")` and even just copy paste values>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution with formula:
[image: solution]

With VBA would be similar but less optimal, you would have to loop through rows and columns and insert corresponding fruit if it exists in column B.

Comment: Maybe you should replace semicolons (;) with commas in the formula

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(C$1,$B2)),C$1;"")`

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(C$1,$B2)),C$1,"")

Comment: But i have to do this for entire column . can i automate it using a button

Comment: If you drag the formula across columns and rows, you will have it for entire column and all rows.

Comment: Thanks, But i want to perform this when user press the button

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it as a VBA code, here is something you can start with:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim my_dict             As Object
    Dim my_str              As String
    Dim my_arr              As Variant
    Dim my_key              As Variant
    Dim l_counter           As Long

    Set my_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    my_str = "ora,gra,app,app,app,man,man" 'Range(Cells(2, 2),cells(6,2))
    my_arr = Split(my_str, ",")

    For l_counter = LBound(my_arr) To UBound(my_arr)
        If my_dict.exists(my_arr(l_counter)) Then
            my_dict(my_arr(l_counter)) = my_dict(my_arr(l_counter)) + 1
        Else
            my_dict.Add my_arr(l_counter), 1
        End If
    Next l_counter

    For Each my_key In my_dict.Keys
        Debug.Print my_key, my_dict(my_key)
    Next my_key


End Sub
```

In your case, you should put a loop for each cell with fruits, writing it to my_str. At the end you would have a nice dictionary, that has all the fruits inside.

Try the code, it works and produces something in the immediate window.

Comment: `my_str = "ora,gra,app,app,app,man,man"` should I write full fruits name

Comment: Write whatever you want. The best is to make sure that `my_str` contains the text from all cells where the fruits are. This you can easily get with a loop.

Comment: I have given more detail in the question